# QuerySelectorAll e NodeList

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema no button, eu tenho uma lista que possoui 22 botões. Os botões tem seus ids respectivamente faq1, fa2, fa3, fa4, faq5, etc. e utilizo `const btnfaqs = document.querySelectorAll('#tirar-duvidas button[id^="faq"]');` que retorna uma NodeList com 22 itens. Ao clicar em um botão ele adiciona classe **`class="flow"`**, que é adicionado ao elemento `<div class="resposta">` que faz com um elemento expanda no html, Porém Todos os botões se expandem no mesmo elemento, Gostaria de expandir um seção especifica.

Segue o código:

```js
const btnfaqs = document.querySelectorAll('#tirar-duvidas button[id^="faq"]');

function toggleFaq(event) {
  if (event.type === 'touchstart') event.preventDefault();

  const faq = document.querySelector('.resposta');
  faq.classList.toggle('flow');
  const flow = faq.classList.contains('flow');
  console.log(faq);
  event.currentTarget.setAttribute('aria-expanded', flow);
  if (flow) {
    event.currentTarget.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Fechar resposta');
  } else {
    event.currentTarget.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Abrir resposta');
  }
}

btnfaqs.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', toggleFaq);
})
```

```html
<ol aria-label="lista de perguntas" id="tirar-duvidas">
   <ol id="ol1">
     <li class="faq">
        <button id="faq1" aria-expanded="false">
           Aceitam Pix?
           <svg aria-hidden="true" id="svg-ask" focusable="false" height="12" viewBox="0 0 17 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path d="M0.616323 0.616323C0.221692 1.01107 0 1.5464 0 2.10458C0 2.66275 0.221692 3.19808 0.616323 3.59283L11.0362 14.0127L0.616323 24.4326C0.232876 24.8296 0.0207002 25.3613 0.0254964 25.9133C0.0302925 26.4652 0.251676 26.9932 0.641965 27.3835C1.03225 27.7737 1.56022 27.9951 2.11215 27.9999C2.66408 28.0047 3.19582 27.7925 3.59283 27.4091L15.501 15.501C15.8956 15.1062 16.1173 14.5709 16.1173 14.0127C16.1173 13.4545 15.8956 12.9192 15.501 12.5245L3.59283 0.616323C3.19808 0.221692 2.66275 0 2.10458 0C1.5464 0 1.01107 0.221692 0.616323 0.616323V0.616323Z" fill="#EBA816" />
          </svg>
       </button>
       <div class="resposta">
          <p>texto apenas para exemplificar</p>
       </div>
     </li>
   </ol>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -2):

Adiciona uma classe tanto no botão quanto no li,

```
<li class="resposta1 flow">
 <button type="button" class="resposta1" onclick="toggleAnswer"/>
 <div>resposta</div>
</li>

function toggleAnswer(e){
 const liToBeExpanded = document.querySelector(`.${e.target.className}`);
 
 liToBeExpanded.toggleClass('closed')
}
```

O estilo padrão da resposta deve ser fechado pela class closed, quando você clicar no botão ele irá pegar o nome da classe do botão e encontrar o li pelo querySelector e depois dar um toggle na classe closed, fazendo com que ele abra.

Acho que é a forma mais imples de se executar...

Comment: A resposta é boa, porém nesse caso uma classe CSS pra cada id de resposta não seria adequado, seria melhor no entanto atribuir um ID pra cada `<li>` e a partir dali ele poder obter o elemento `li#resposta1 > div.resposta` e alterar a classe ali e por ai vai nos outros elementos.